# At apache server, several address to one domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have been developing web application using php framework - codeigniter at apache server.
For example, My server address has three address - 10.*.*.*, www.test.com, test.com

In codeigniter framework, I set the base url in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.test.com/';
```

so I want that clients' requests will be redirect the www.test.com address.

That is,

```
http://test.com/   =======> http://www.test.com/
http://10.*.*.*/   =======> http://www.test.com/
```

In documentation, it talk me I have to use .htaccess file.
But, I don't know about it.
How to redirect the several address to one address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess file for the site you can use the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

In case you haven't used mod-rewrite before, it needs to be enabled on your server. The .htaccess file needs to go in your document root folder, usually public or public_html.

Here are some instructions for enabling modrewrite on apache under Ubuntu. If you let me know what server or hosting you are using I may be able to point you to some better instructions. Note: You will probably find it's already enabled for you!

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how to move http://www.test.com/admin? I have /var/www/html/admin diretory, and I want to make .htaccess file in this directory...

Comment: You can simply put it wherever your document root is, so if it's in the admin folder then just put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

1st condition of each block means: host is not empty
2nd condition of 1st block means: host doesn't match www.*
2nd condition on 2nd block means: host matches an ip address starting with 10, it would match invalid ip aswell such as. 10.25**6**.*.*

Then redirecting (or rewriting) the request where 301 means permanent and L means stop rewriting.

For this to work, you'll need mod_rewrite enabled in apache.